# Bypassing "Honeypots" when scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I've been trying to extract some data from a webpage, and it uses some peculiar methods of detecting bots that i need to bypass.
I first had to bypass an annoying `CAPTCHA` but now another problem has emerged.

The webpage uses a (what seems to be)random link generator to give me the data i want. On a browser only one button is visible, but looking through the source, I see multiple randomly-generated buttons in the same area like this:

```html
...
<div id='BA405352A9' style='display:none;'><button type="button" value="Upgrade level" class="build" onclick="window.location.href = 'dorf2.php?a=20&c=A230134'; return false;">
<div class="button-container"><div class="button-position"><div class="btl"><div class="btr"><div class="btc"></div></div></div>
<div class="bml"><div class="bmr"><div class="bmc"></div></div></div><div class="bbl"><div class="bbr"><div class="bbc"></div></div></div>
</div><div class="button-contents">Enter</div></div></button></div><div id='075A1762B3' style='display:none;'><button type="button" value="Upgrade level" class="build" onclick="window.location.href = 'dorf2.php?a=20&c=7294A7B'; return false;">
<div class="button-container"><div class="button-position"><div class="btl"><div class="btr"><div class="btc"></div></div></div>
<div class="bml"><div class="bmr"><div class="bmc"></div></div></div><div class="bbl"><div class="bbr"><div class="bbc"></div></div></div>
</div><div class="button-contents">Enter</div></div></button></div><div id='453A2A0469' style='display:none;'><button type="button" value="Upgrade level" class="build" onclick="window.location.href = 'dorf2.php?a=20&c=9646432'; return false;">
<div class="button-container"><div class="button-position"><div class="btl"><div class="btr"><div class="btc"></div></div></div>
<div class="bml"><div class="bmr"><div class="bmc"></div></div></div><div class="bbl"><div class="bbr"><div class="bbc"></div></div></div>
</div><div class="button-contents">Enter</div></div></button></div><div id='302B375583' style='display:none;'><button type="button" value="Upgrade level" class="build" onclick="window.location.href = 'dorf2.php?a=20&c=933A29B'; return false;">
<div class="button-container"><div class="button-position"><div class="btl"><div class="btr"><div class="btc"></div></div></div>
<div class="bml"><div class="bmr"><div class="bmc"></div></div></div><div class="bbl"><div class="bbr"><div class="bbc"></div></div></div>
</div><div class="button-contents">Enter</div></div></button></div><div id='08171153B4' style='display:none;'><button type="button" value="Upgrade level" class="build" onclick="window.location.href = 'dorf2.php?a=20&c=3447182'; return false;">
<div class="button-container"><div class="button-position"><div class="btl"><div class="btr"><div class="btc"></div></div></div>
<div class="bml"><div class="bmr"><div class="bmc"></div></div></div><div class="bbl"><div class="bbr"><div class="bbc"></div></div></div>
</div><div class="button-contents">Enter</div></div></button></div><div id='20813B7B10' style='display:none;'><button type="button" value="Upgrade level" class="build" onclick="window.location.href = 'dorf2.php?a=20&c=6B96496'; return false;">
<div class="button-container"><div class="button-position"><div class="btl"><div class="btr"><div class="btc"></div></div></div>
<div class="bml"><div class="bmr"><div class="bmc"></div></div></div><div class="bbl"><div class="bbr"><div class="bbc"></div></div></div>
</div><div class="button-contents">Enter</div></div></button></div><div id='6661917AB6' style='display:none;'><button type="button" value="Upgrade level" class="build" onclick="window.location.href = 'dorf2.php?a=20&c=9AA8604'; return false;">
<div class="button-container"><div class="button-position"><div class="btl"><div class="btr"><div class="btc"></div></div></div>
<div class="bml"><div class="bmr"><div class="bmc"></div></div></div><div class="bbl"><div class="bbr"><div class="bbc"></div></div></div>
</div><div class="button-contents">Enter</div></div></button></div><div id='1646980B02' style='display:none;'><button type="button" value="Upgrade level" class="build" onclick="window.location.href = 'dorf2.php?a=20&c=5841731'; return false;">
<div class="button-container"><div class="button-position"><div class="btl"><div class="btr"><div class="btc"></div></div></div>
<div class="bml"><div class="bmr"><div class="bmc"></div></div></div><div class="bbl"><div class="bbr"><div class="bbc"></div></div></div>
</div><div class="button-contents">Enter</div></div></button></div></div><script language="javascript">
...
```

According to the source it seems the initial HTTP GET request contains only invisible buttons, And somehow after the `CSS` loads the "correct" button becomes visible?

I'm not that experienced with designs like this(or designing websites in general). How do they work? And how can i mimic the browser's behavior to hopefully bypass them?

Comment: maybe you can buy a license and get access to an api...?

Comment: @thebjorn Unfortunately such API doesn't exist yet

Comment: This seems like a question that should be emailed to the website owner. Clearly, they don't want bots scraping their site, so maybe you could come to some sort of agreement.

Comment: Most likely the css is keyed to the unique id. Since styles can inherit from other styles I would be surprised if the style is not also obfuscated through multiple layers.

Comment: The website was last update on 2012! I don't think any person in their right mind would  want to look for an API or contact the developers at this stage. As for whether I'm "allowed" to do this, webpages like don't ask me whether they're "allowed" to use my private info, or whether they're "allowed" to keep logs of my behavior and overwhelm me with ads . So i think it's perfectly fine for me to scrape anything i want from this website.

Answer (score 2):

I was Finally able to access the data, It turns out the `CSS` tag was being set by some Javascript when the page was loading. After taking a look at the scripts I found there were a lot of data being generated (probably server-side) that i needed to extract first.
After hours of looking I was finally able to track down the functions that the Javascript was using to edit the data. there were a bunch of them, and the server randomized the order of using them to further obfuscate any attempts to crack the algorithm:

```
function showbt(sid) {
            return (dM(aM(bM(fM(gM(cM(sid)))))))
        }
```

Here, the order was randomly generated, and 2 of the functions were injected inside the webpage source and had to be replaced every time.

I was able to completely translate the Javascript to Python, as well as extract and update the functions and their order of usage using `re` and `requests`, then using the generated Python code to finally crack the encryption.
(An example of a translation:)

```
var _0x7052 = ["", "\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68", "\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72", "\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66"];

function aarf(_0xb5a3x2) {
    var _0xb5a3x3 = 0;
    var _0xb5a3x4 = 0;
    var _0xb5a3x5 = _0x7052[0];
    for (i = 0; i < _0xb5a3x2[_0x7052[1]]; i += 1) {
        _0xb5a3x3 = stream[_0x7052[3]](_0xb5a3x2[_0x7052[2]](i, 1));
        _0xb5a3x3 = _0xb5a3x3 * _0xb5a3x3 + 6 * _0xb5a3x3 + 6246;
        _0xb5a3x3 = _0xb5a3x3 % stream[_0x7052[1]];
        _0xb5a3x5 += stream[_0x7052[2]](_0xb5a3x3, 1);
    };
    return _0xb5a3x5;
};
```

translated UTF-8 to text(here it was used to obfuscate the code):

```
var _0x7052 = ["", "length", "substr", "indexOf"];

function aarf(_0xb5a3x2) {
    var _0xb5a3x3 = 0;
    var _0xb5a3x4 = 0;
    var _0xb5a3x5 = _0x7052[0];
    for (i = 0; i < _0xb5a3x2[_0x7052[1]]; i += 1) {
        _0xb5a3x3 = stream[_0x7052[3]](_0xb5a3x2[_0x7052[2]](i, 1));
        _0xb5a3x3 = _0xb5a3x3 * _0xb5a3x3 + 6 * _0xb5a3x3 + 6246;
        _0xb5a3x3 = _0xb5a3x3 % stream[_0x7052[1]];
        _0xb5a3x5 += stream[_0x7052[2]](_0xb5a3x3, 1);
    };
    return _0xb5a3x5;
};
```

and finally after substituting the array functions of the JS and rewriting in Python we get:

```py
def aarf(_0xb5a3x2) :
    _0xb5a3x3 = 0
    _0xb5a3x4 = 0
    _0xb5a3x5 = ""
    for i in range(0, len(_0xb5a3x2), 1): 
        _0xb5a3x3 = stream.index(_0xb5a3x2[i:i+1])
        _0xb5a3x3 = _0xb5a3x3 * _0xb5a3x3 +6 * _0xb5a3x3 +6246 #REPNUM2
        _0xb5a3x3 = _0xb5a3x3 % len(stream)
        _0xb5a3x5 += stream[math.ceil(_0xb5a3x3):math.ceil(_0xb5a3x3)+1]
    return _0xb5a3x5
#note that the REPNUM comment indicates there are 2 randomly generated numbers in this line, and they'll have to be extracted from the webpage and injected into this code.
```

But not yet...

The buttons themselves were being generated with the webpage, and the ID's in them were also encrypted, so i had to go through the same steps as above to also decrypt the button ID's.

Then all that was left was to match the decrypted button ID with the decrypted Javascript code's output and find the correct button to use!

---

To anyone wanting do anything similar, remember that the Javascript used for decrypting the right button is ALWAYS included in the webpage somehow(otherwise your browser couldn't find the right one either!), so all you need to do is to analyse the webpage and how it works very carefully and then try to reverse-engineer it's behavior in order to exploit the encryption.

I was able to do it with not much prior experience of javascript or HTML, so if I can do it, so can you!
Another workaround would be to use `Selenium`, but that doesn't have a fraction of the power and speed of using good old `requests`!

Comment: You definitely took the long away around. Selenium is rather easy to set up and saves you a lot of time compared to this. But it won't beat recaptchas.